# Will the foreign key constraint throw an error while restoring a database?

Tags: mysql, import

I have never faced any issue like this, but I am just curious. Let's say I have a database dump file with me and I want to import the dump file to another database.
There are 2 tables table_A and table_B. table_B contains a primary key and table_A contains the foreign key. And serially, table_A is first and then table_B.

So, when I update the database table_A will be created with a foreign key and next table_B will be created that contains the primary key.

So, will there be any error in this case?

Comment: Which error message?  And please show `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: Hi rick, i haven't faced any problem like this, i am just curious that if i get a database as mentioned in the question, will there be any issues while restoring it ?

Comment: If the data was 'consistent' before, then there should be no errors during the load.  There are probably ways to create inconsistencies and leave them unchecked.  (See techniques for disabling/enabling `FOREIGN KEYs`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of backup, that can indeed happen. It's therefore recommended to disable foreign key checks before the restore, e.g. with

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and re-enabling them afterwards with

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

This has another advantage: MySQL won't check the foreign key for every single imported record, but for all records at once. This will speed up your restore.

See [Disabling foreign key checks on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938786/disabling-foreign-key-checks-on-the-command-line) on Stack Overflow.